Splitting data into training, validation, and test sets without overlapping IDs and still balancing target classes
I need to split a large dataset into set proportions of training, validation, and test sets while ensuring the following:

Keep unique IDs in each set. No ID can be in more than one set.
At each shuffling of data, there needs to be at least one occurrence of each level ("hot", "warm", "cold) in the training, validation, and test sets.

data <- data.frame(IDs = c(001, 001, 001, 
                           002, 002, 002, 002, 
                           003, 003, 003, 003, 
                           004, 004, 004, 004, 004, 004, 
                           005, 005, 005, 005, 005, 
                           006, 006, 006, 006,
                           007, 007, 007,
                           008, 008, 
                           009, 009, 
                           010, 010, 010),
                   var1 = c(0102, 0210, 0405, 
                            0318, 0629, 1201,0101, 
                            0923, 0702, 0710, 0801,
                            0203, 0501, 1204, 0516, 0112, 1005, 
                            1101, 1125, 1020, 0112, 0310,
                            0203, 0401, 0607, 0811,
                            1010, 1212, 0707,
                            0430, 0428,
                            1030, 1008,
                            0501, 0511, 0601),
                   var2 = c("cold", "cold", "cold", 
                            "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm",
                            "cold", "cold", "cold", "cold", 
                            "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm",   
                            "hot", "hot", "hot", "hot", "hot",
                            "cold", "cold", "cold", "cold", 
                            "hot", "hot", "hot",
                            "warm", "warm",
                            "hot", "hot",
                            "cold", "cold", "cold"))

I've tried using the data splitting packages caret(fx = createDataPartition()) and splitTools (fx = partition()), as well as dplyr sampling functions but the grouping they apply ensures that each ID appears in all sets.
It's okay to reduce the dataset. Here is one of many attempts guided by an existing Stack Overflow question:
assignments <- data %>%
        select(IDs, var2) %>%
        distinct(IDs) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(Group= sample(c("validation", "training", "test"), 1, 
                             prob = c(0.70, 0.20, 0.10)))
data %>%
  left_join(assignments, data, by = "IDs")

This attempt neglects that the probability argument is *not setting a proportion. It also doesn't ensure that all levels appear in training, validation, and test sets.

Using rsample from tidymodels to group and stratify:
data <- data.frame(
  IDs = c(
    001, 001, 001,
    002, 002, 002, 002,
    003, 003, 003, 003,
    004, 004, 004, 004, 004, 004,
    005, 005, 005, 005, 005,
    006, 006, 006, 006,
    007, 007, 007,
    008, 008,
    009, 009,
    010, 010, 010
  ),
  var1 = c(
    0102, 0210, 0405,
    0318, 0629, 1201, 0101,
    0923, 0702, 0710, 0801,
    0203, 0501, 1204, 0516, 0112, 1005,
    1101, 1125, 1020, 0112, 0310,
    0203, 0401, 0607, 0811,
    1010, 1212, 0707,
    0430, 0428,
    1030, 1008,
    0501, 0511, 0601
  ),
  var2 = c(
    "cold", "cold", "cold",
    "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm",
    "cold", "cold", "cold", "cold",
    "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm", "warm",
    "hot", "hot", "hot", "hot", "hot",
    "cold", "cold", "cold", "cold",
    "hot", "hot", "hot",
    "warm", "warm",
    "hot", "hot",
    "cold", "cold", "cold"
  )
)

library(rsample)

# Keep IDs together and stratify var2
data_split <- data |> group_initial_split(group = IDs, strata = var2)
train <- training(data_split)
test <- testing(data_split)

# Group v-fold cross-validation
train |> group_vfold_cv(group = IDs, strata = var2, v = 2)
#> # Group 2-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   splits          id       
#>   <list>          <chr>    
#> 1 <split [13/15]> Resample1
#> 2 <split [15/13]> Resample2

Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0

What do you do with the resamples? This is where I keep getting stuck on this problem. There are several ML concepts I don't quite understand yet.

There are some great tidymodels screencasts you could take a look at, e.g. re using the rsamples for model tuning.

Alternative train/test/validation split not using cross validation.

Also recommend this tidymodels book (free online).

Thanks for the video series recommendation. :) I tried initial_validation_split earlier. Now down a rabbit hole about the faux pas of data augmentation prior to splitting. Using initial_val, I'd have to figure out a way to fix the numbers so that the test set still gets one observation of each level.

Upsampling is one way to increase levels with few observations. Or you could lump together the smallest levels into one called “other”.

I've used upsampling through the caret package. However, what seems to need investigating is applying it after the data split. When you're working with a grouping + stratified variables, it's trickier?
